# Async "mymodule.nocache.js" script loading, onModuleLoad not fired

Tags: gwt

Is there any way to load "mymodule.nocache.js" with script async tag and get onModuleLoad fired?
Both of the script "mymodule.nocache.js" and "BDAC1610913660F7525C05DB3B100E5D.cache.html" are loaded fine, but "onModuleLoad" never started.

Another similar case - I want to inject  GWT application from JS (on button press for example). No luck with "onModuleLoad" again.

The hint is in GWT bootstrap order:

> Once the GWT selection script has started, its onModuleLoad() can be
>   called at any point after the outer document has been parsed.

Are there anyway to start GWT application manually, without "onModuleLoad() can be called at any point after the outer document has been parsed."